# Writing a script which converts and use xload

Tags: bash, imagemagick, xming

I am using ImageMagick. I am trying to write a script which launch 'n' convert runs. 'n' is the number given by user. The script must wait for all 'n' background/concurrent processes to complete before launching a new set of 'n' processes (or the number of processors left if fewer than 'n'.

Here is my code:

```
  #!/bin/bash

 for(( i=1; i<$n; i++))
 do 
   xload -update 1 &
   convert "${dir}"/*.jpg -flip -set filename:t '%d/%t-change' '%[filename:t].jpg'
   wait 
 done
```

How can I convert first 'n' files followed by the next 'n' files...so on

Comment: Okay...  Where did you get stuck?  What have you tried?

Comment: I dont know how to use xload

Comment: Google 'gnu parallel' for a tool that might be useful - and no. it isn't a simple tool to use, you have to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
xload &
parallel convert {} -flip -set filename:t '%d/%t-change' '%[filename:t].jpg' ::: "${dir}"/*.jpg
```