# imagemagick convertion in segments

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, imagemagick, for

How can I convert 5 pictures at a time followed by a `wait`,
then the next 5 pictures in a directory, on `N` pictures.
Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.jpg;
do 
   xload -update 1 &
   convert "${dir}"/*.jpg -flip -set filename:t '%d/%t-change'  '%[filename:t].jpg' &
   wait 
done
```

Comment: Previously http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/319976/117549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a count:

- For each file, increment the count
- If the count reaches 5, `wait` and reset the count

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
for i in *.jpg; do 
   xload -update 1 &
   convert "${dir}/$i" -flip -set filename:t '%d/%t-change'  '%[filename:t].jpg' &
   ((count++))
   if [ $count = 5 ]; then
       wait
       count=0
   fi
done
if [ $count != 0 ]; then
    wait
fi
```